# Eigen::Matrix modulus fails to compile

Tags: eigen3

I'v implemented the modulus of a matrix as follows, but it fails to compile :

```
const double dPI = std::acos( double(-1.) );
using baseSpaceVd = Matrix<double, 4, 1>;
baseSpaceVd  M(0,1,2,3);

M = M.unaryExpr( []( const baseSpaceVd::Scalar x ) { return x%(2*dPI); } );
```

Compilation error message is :

```
../src/COpdCtrl.cpp: In lambda function:
../src/COpdCtrl.cpp:187:85: error: invalid operands of types ‘const Scalar {aka const double}’ and ‘double’ to binary ‘operator%’
   curGDerr = curGDerr.unaryExpr( []( const baseSpaceVd::Scalar x ) { return x%(2*dPI); } );
```

This fix works but I'am afraid it degrades the performance :

```
M = M.unaryExpr( []( const baseSpaceVd::Scalar x ) { return fmod( x, (2*dPI); } );
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Eigen. `x % y` just does not work for `double` in C++. If you really want this fast, you need to provide a functor which also works for SIMD-packets (or make a feature request to have that integrated into Eigen).

Comment: Dear chtz, many thanks for your answer. Where to send my feature request ? Cheers !

Comment: Just found this was already requested: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=467

Comment: Thanks for those very useful links